# Can I play erotic video games (digital version) in the UAE?

Tags: legal, uae, sex

I'll start working in Dubai next month and now plan to install some downloaded video games and porn films to kill *certain* time.

Reading many Q&A in TSE, I learn that:

1. Don't use a VPN to watch porn,
2. Don't bring too many sex toys,
3. Don't let anybody know of one's masturbation,
4. No flirting in public.

So here is what I plan to do.
I'll install all those dirty videos and games on my laptop before entering the UAE. They don't require Internet access, but some of them are Steam games. I will use them only in my private space. (Nobody will spy on me there, right?)

By doing so, is there any possibility that I'll get fined, imprisoned, or expelled?

Comment: > fined, prisoned, or expelled 
I fear you may be forgetting more dire consequences that are possible, even though unlikely.

Comment: *or worse, expelled*

Comment: I think this question should really be *"Can I legally play erotic video games in UAE?"* Asking whether / how you can do illegal things in a jurisdiction sounds like it should be off topic, even if you don't like the law (which I don't). In any case, given the potential penalties in the UAE, I would strongly advise OP not to do anything illegal.

Comment: *Don't bring too many sex toy.* I now have additional questions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because wind-up

Comment: Please, please do not close the question. It pertains to the use of cryptography to retain human rights suppressed by capricious random laws. It's a very important humanitarian issue. And yes, nothing funny about that, the right to masturbate is an unalienable human right.

Comment: @abligh, I demur. The jurisprudence makes a distinction between _malum in se_ and _malum prohibitum_. The former is a crime which is wrong "by and of itself," like murder. The latter is an arbitrary prohibition. Some of these laws clearly violate human rights. It is not morally wrong to find loopholes to bypass such laws, and may not conscientiously be off-topic of Travel.SO. The question how to avoid criminal penalties for masturbation is serious. "Just don't do it, because it's illegal in _X_" is a very wrong answer. It's a health issue for men after 50 (risk of prostate cancer), for one.

Comment: (serious) How often to UAE official search portable devices when coming in Dubai ? is that really something that normal people should be afraid of ?

Comment: hi @kkm this is a silly "beavis & butthead" level wind-up and should be closed.  you political views, and superb technical knowledge, can be discussed elsewhere.  note that you can masturbate endlessly, 24/7, in UAE.  In almost every country, certain videos are illegal, and the different types of material that are illegal vary from place to place. none of this has any connection to a "right" or otherwise to masturbate.  the ticked answer already fully gives the obvious answer to the question in one sentence.

Comment: @Fattie, the UN disagrees. The right to health is a fundamental human right. The Universal Declaration has nothing to do with politics: the UN transcends politics by its definition. If someone needs an erotic computer game or toys, which is obviously harmless, to get off (it becomes difficult with age) and needs to get off to stay healthy (this is a medical fact), then this is a very real and serious issue. Equating "illegal" with "wrong" is a fallacy. The world is full of laws that are clearly at odd with human rights. The ticked answer has no advice on how not to get caught at the border.

Comment: @Fattie, think of this. The UK govt prosecuted one of the greatest mathematicians of all time, Alan Turing, who might have changed the course of WWII with his codebreaking work, and drove him to suicide. His crime was homosexuality (it still is in UAE). Yes, he committed a crime under statute. In your opinion, was he a criminal who had to be punished? We had all sorts of things criminalized or banned: gay sex, sex between unmarried people, porn,  interracial marriage... Heck, we burned people alive for apostasy. Saudi still behead for it. Do you really think it was and is alright, because law?

Comment: howdy @kkm it's simply not the forum to discuss these issues.  the question is fully answered in the first sentence of the ticked answer.

Comment: I see two easy options, go on and take the job and do without the porn or if you can not do without the porn, do not take the job and stay home. Neither is breaking the law.

Comment: @Willeke sorry, that must really be the wrong forum. The red spots on the map in your profile are within the modern Westernized world, governed by respected democratically enacted laws. Believe me, there are very different lands, very different kinds of "laws", just seeing what they've been enacted for urges one to throw up in disgust. There are people who have no travel choice, e.g. humanitarian workers. Many people live flying low under the radar of this "law" to survive and do their job. Glad I had the time to pass the info on before your forum "law" noticed it—very familiar feeling! :)

Comment: @CGCampbell sure, here we're running into a culture clash. The right to health is declared fundamental by the UN. Is the UN an authority? Maybe. Is the UN higher an authority than your imam to you? Definitely not. For me? I don't care. Sorry, I understand it sounds offensive to you, but this is why we the people don't feel it's wrong to murder each other—not even over over our true beliefs—no, we find it's right to murder people over the "State religion." Note you're not saying "faith," you're saying "religion." It's ok, it's just who we are. I accept that. This is why I must hide from you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's really just asking for an opinion on how good the OP is at breaking laws and hiding that fact. Or a wind up...

Comment: @CGCampbell 1.I never said it wasn't illegal or against Qu'ran (or a certain interpretation of it—people wage wars and kill each other over them). 2.I'm sorry about the wrong inference that you were a Muslim, correction taken. Apologies for sounding _ad hominem_. I did not intend that. 3.Don't beat the strawman: I never mentioned "unalienable right to sex," this is a most ridiculous nonsense. 4.My goal was to convey a piece of important information to the OP despite censorship; my mission is accomplished. I have no time to continue this argument, sorry.

Answer (score 29):

The games and films you intend to bring are almost certainly **illegal to import or possess** in the UAE.

Is it *unlikely* that you will be caught?  Yes.  Is there "any possibility" that you get fined, imprisoned or expelled?  Absolutely: for example, your computer might be examined or confiscated for some completely unrelated reason, and they might find the illegal materials then.

Comment: You mean there is possibility that I will be asked to turn on my computer and let the airport's security to check everything? (I wonder can I slide in by compressing those files into an innocent archive...)

Comment: @BigMacBook Border controls are notorious. And that applies everywhere, not just in the UAE. Border security in most countries has far-reaching powers and very little restrictions on how to use them. Basically you can't expect any privacy and they can search anything on the slightest pretense (or for no reason at all). Zipping of Rarring (with password) won't safe you. (Might actually make matters worse as obviously you have something to hide.) And if you don't disclose the password they will just throw you in jail or deport you anyway.

Comment: You could definitely use cryptography in a savy and educated way. Immigration attendants do not have time to fully scrutiny a *random* traveler's laptop

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ The chance that they discover such material if it is well hidden is probably very slight. You are right about that. But would you be willing to risk it? Especially if you are checked and they find something, they might consider your attempt at "hiding it" as aggravating circumstances.

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ> said traveler is much less random if he is uneasy because he knows he risks much. That's the kind of things border controls are trained to recognize.

Comment: it's always just ... sad ... when people think there's a technological !!! solution !!! to dealing with men with guns.  ("This is how we can trick them!")  They'll just shut you in a plain room for 30 or 40 hours.  Then they'll put you on every possible list of sex offenders and worse internationally.  Then they'll throw you out of the country.  Then for the rest of your life when you go *anywhere*, do *anything*, apply for *any* job or file *any* paperwork you'll have to state that yes, you were thrown out of a country - for sex related issues.  zip!  crypt!  Good grief.

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ sure, if you know exactly what you are doing and are confident and skilled enough to lie to authorities that are trained to pick out lies. All it takes is some scanning program finding something slightly unusual and then they decide to spend a lot more time investigating you .